# How to use SQL in terminal?

Tags: command-line, sql

I want to create simple tables, insert values in it, and do queries.
How to perform them in the terminal?

Answer (score 10):

**Here is the syntax to execute sql statement from terminal**

I'm assuming that you are using `MySQL`.

**Syntax:**

```
mysql -u user_name -p password -e 'SQL Query' database
```

Clearificance:

```
-u : Specify mysql database user name
-p : Prompt for password
-e : Execute sql query
database : Specify database name
```

**Example:**

- If you want to create a table `person` then:

  ```
  mysql -u root -p -e 'Create table person(PersonID int, LastName varchar(255), FirstName varchar(255))' mydb
  ```

  where  `root` is the username, `mydb` is the name of the database.
  Similary you can execute any query you want.
- If you want to `insert` values in `person`:

  ```
  mysql -u root -p -e 'Insert into person(PersonID,LastName,FirstName) Values(100,"Kumar","Saurav")' mydb
  ```
- If you want to select all the information from `person` and want to save in a file:

  ```
  mysql -u root -p -e 'Select * from person' mydb > personinfo
  ```

**And of-course you can create a database using terminal itself**

- To create database **mydb** execute following command in terminal:

  ```
  mysql -u root -p -e 'create database mydb'
  ```

  it will silently create a database **mydb** without giving any message/output.
- To list all the databases execute this command in terminal:

  ```
  mysql -u root -p -e 'show databases'
  ```

Hope it helps you.. Reply if you need further assistance..

Answer (score 9):

You make a database by typing

```
 mysql
```

In the prompt you enter, you then start by creating your database (as explained by onik in the comments):

```
 CREATE DATABASE dbname
```

Once you have made that database, you can experiment with it. **You can simply type `mysql` in a terminal** and you can get do anything sql related you want. It is possible that you have create to a role in your database with your username.

As described in Sauruv's answer you can also connect to the database as follows (without the space between p and your password or better, just do not use the -p option and you will get a password prompt [credits go to onik]):

**Syntax:**

```
mysql -u user_name -ppassword dbname

-u : Specify mysql database user name
-p : Prompt for password
dbname : Specify database name
```

Comment: Actually, the syntax you specified only connects to the specified database, it doesn't create it. You'll have to first connect without specifying a database and run `CREATE DATABASE [dbname]`. Furthermore, if you specify the password on the command line (not recommended, the syntax is `mysql -u user_name -ppassword database`, without the space between p and your password. You can also omit the password here and MySQL will prompt you for it, which is safer.

Comment: @onik you are absolutely right. Next time, feel free to either edit my answer or to copy it and elaborate it into your own answer. By way of thanks, I have found a good answer of you on another question and I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

### [`mycli`](https://github.com/dbcli/mycli)

`mysql` default console is fine and pretty, but maybe prettier is [`mycli`](https://github.com/dbcli/mycli) (and it Postgres alternative, [`pgcli`](https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli)).

**Installation**: On Ubuntu 16.04+ is on official repos: `sudo apt install mycli`

```
$ mycli --help
Usage: mycli [OPTIONS] [DATABASE]

  A MySQL terminal client with auto-completion and syntax highlighting.

  Examples:
    - mycli my_database
    - mycli -u my_user -h my_host.com my_database
    - mycli mysql://my_user@my_host.com:3306/my_database
```

[image: screenshot]

#### Reference

- [HomePage](http://mycli.net)
- [Documentation](http://mycli.net/docs)
- [Github repo](https://github.com/dbcli/mycli)
- [nixCraft post](https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/mycli-awesome-mysqlmariadbpercona-mysql-client-with-auto-completion-and-syntax-highlighting/) about `mycli`

Answer (score 1):

mysql is a simple command-line tool. mysql is command line and it is very easy to use. Invoke it from the prompt of your command interpreter as follows:

```
$ mysql
```

Output

```
mysql>
```

You may need to provide mysql username, password and hostname, use:

```
$ mysql --user=your-user-name --password=your-password

mysql>
```

**To list database type the following command**

```
mysql> show databases;
```

Output

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

information_schema and mysql are name of databases. To use these database and to list available tables type the following two commands:

```
mysql> use mysql;
```

Output:

```
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
Database changed
```

Now list tables:

```
mysql> show tables;
```

Output:

```
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| func                      |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| host                      |
| proc                      |
| procs_priv                |
| tables_priv               |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
| user                      |
+---------------------------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [sqlline](https://github.com/julianhyde/sqlline) which could connect to any rdbms (Oracle, mysql, postgres, h2 and others), also csv, cassandra, elastic-search, mongo (via apache-calcite).

There is a [project demos page with short demo videos](https://github.com/julianhyde/sqlline/wiki/Demos) 
It provides multiline-editing, syntax highlighting, smart autocompletion, dialect support.

It could be embedded and no need to install it.